# ListBox1 и ProgressBar1

Tags: c#

Всем привет, я уже мозг сломал не могу разобраться как правильно работать с этими элементами....

1. Как в ListBox'e сделать так что при изменение выделенного пункта, менялось значение TextBox'ov, вот например выбераю из списка Вася Петров, а TextBox'ы заполняются, там сколько ему лет, возраст, рост и.т.д. Вот не могу такое надумать.
2. Как сделать так что например progressbar1 показывал сколько реально остлоась загружать данные, а не просто бежал. Вот к примеру идет считывание с БД, и прогресс бар показывал сколько ещё осталось(без %).

Answer (score 1):

1. OnClick и Selected
2. Запускать запрос в ассинхронном режиме. Используйте ,например, ADO (TADOStoredProcedure.ExecuteOptions.eoAsyncExecute := true) и курите мануал по событиям TADOConnection. Если прогресс выполнения запроса не критичен - то лучше не начинайте, больше геморроя словите чем реальной пользы

Comment: Нет, по прогресс бару не горит. А вот по listbox'y да... можно по подробнее?

Comment: Пишу про Дельфи, не думаю что в С# сильно по другому. TListBox лучше заменить на TListView, при вставке элемента - добавлять идентификатор. Примерно так:

var ItemData:^integer;
begin
   with ListView.Items.Add begin
      Caption:='text'   
      New(ItemData)
      ItemData^:=id
      Data:=ItemData
   end;
end;

и в событии OnChange грузить его инфу по integer(Item.Data^)

Если горит на Listbox - вспомогательный массив идентификаторов по строке или по индексу строки

Answer (score 1):

У `ListBox` обязательно будет событие `SelectedIndexChanged`. Подпишитесь на него и в обработчике смотрите на свойство `SelectedItem`. Значение этого свойства используйте для расчёта того, что надо поместить в `TextBox`'ы.

У `ProgressBar` свойство `Style` установите в `Blocks` или `Continuous`. После этого положение прогресса задавайте свойством `Value`. Чтобы `Value` был в процентах, свойство `Minimum` должно быть установлено в 0, а `Maximum` - в 100.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа:

```
...
class Person
{
   string firstName;
   string lastName;
}
...
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
...
Person temp = new Person();
temp.firstName = "Vas9";
temp.lastName = "Pupkin";
persons.Add(temp);
...
if (myListBox.SelectedItem == 1)
{
   myTextBoxFirstName.Text = persons[1].firstName;
   myTextBoxlastName.Text = persons[1].lastName;
}
...
```